# AltBeacon setLayout for Gimbal beacons on android

Tags: android, xamarin, ibeacon, altbeacon, gimbal

I would like the Android AltBeacon Library to be able to properly detect Gimbal beacons. I know that Gimbal beacons have encrypted identifiers, so these cannot be read directly. But I would at least like to share code that can detect that one is around.

Here is what I have:

Code to detect a Gimbal beacon (without reading encrypted identifiers):

```
BeaconManager beaconManager = BeaconManager.getInstanceForApplication(this);
BeaconManager.getBeaconParsers().add(new BeaconParser().setBeaconLayout("m:0-3=ad7700c6"));
beaconManager.bind(this);
```

I did find the Gimbal layout here [What is the correct BeaconLayout for Estimote and Gimbal beacons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044046/what-is-the-correct-beaconlayout-for-estimote-and-gimbal-beacons)

But the layout is missing bouth i and p keys.

Here is an exampel of a working layout for an Estimote beacon

```
iBeaconParser.SetBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");
```

Does anybody (especially folks from Gimbal) have any information on the correct Gimbal layout. I would love to know the full service UUIDs as well as any other readable fields sent in the advertisements.

Comment: My understanding is that the identifier is encrypted and you cannot access it directly with the layout.   The power may be accessible, but we would need somebody from Gimbal to reveal that info, or we would need somebody to reverse engineer it.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. I have manage to find the Gimbal beacon with iOS.

Comment: If you use the Gimbal app or SDK it has the ability to decrypt the identifier.