# Gimbal SDK v2+ Demo App is not Working

Tags: android, ibeacon, android-ibeacon, beacon, gimbal

***No beacon sighiting and no place monitoring for device: InFocus Bingo50 (Android 6.0) ***

Samsung, Android Core OS phones runs perfectly, problem in InFocus M460 Bingo50 (Android 6.0, skin inLife UI 2.0). ***what should i do for scan beacon in this device.***. Beacons are already register in Gimbal Manager.

I tried  some ways, but do not get any result.

**Try1:** Make actual app same as Gimbal SDK 2.36 provided For Android. not work for Infocus bingo50 but samsung Galaxy note5, Android one works perfectly.

**Try2:** Make Simple Basic app for Beacon sighting and place monitoring (geofence). still Geofence's visit and exit works but Beaon is not scan, no logs in InFocus Bingo50. other device works perfectly.

**Try3:** AltBeacon Lib used. works perfectly but not get Identifier, only get one beacon scan info while 2 beacons are already switch on. client requirement and advice to just used Gimbal SDK.
[Acording to this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25044046/what-is-the-correct-beaconlayout-for-estimote-and-gimbal-beacons)

Try2:
    MainActivity.java

```
 package com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import com.gimbal.android.Gimbal;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    LocationPermissions permissions;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        listAdapter.add("Setting Gimbal API Key");
        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Gimbal.setApiKey(this.getApplication(),
                "a252edba-981a-4b7e-b668-38661b616415");

        if (permissions == null) {
            permissions = new LocationPermissions(this);
        }
        permissions.checkAndRequestPermission(listAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
            String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        this.permissions.onRequestPermissionResult(requestCode, permissions,
                grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
   }
```

LocationPermissions.java

```
package com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android;

import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.gimbal.android.BeaconEventListener;
import com.gimbal.android.BeaconManager;
import com.gimbal.android.BeaconSighting;
import com.gimbal.android.CommunicationManager;
import com.gimbal.android.PlaceEventListener;
import com.gimbal.android.PlaceManager;
import com.gimbal.android.Visit;
import android.util.Log;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class LocationPermissions implements DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "LocationPermissions";
public static final int LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
static private Activity activity;

public LocationPermissions(Activity activity) {
    this.activity = activity;
}

private PlaceManager placeManager;
private PlaceEventListener placeEventListener;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;

private BeaconManager beaconManager;
private BeaconEventListener beaconEventListener;

public void checkAndRequestPermission(ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter) {
    this.listAdapter = listAdapter;
    if (isLocationPermissionEnabled()) {
        enablePlaceMonitoring();
    } else {
        requestLocationPermission();
    }
}

public boolean isLocationPermissionEnabled() {
    return ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this.activity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
}

public void requestLocationPermission() {
    if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this.activity,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {
        showMessageOKCancel(
                "Permitting us to access your location will entitle you to receive exclusive offers when you visit our stores. Please allow us to access your location so that we can better help you navigate our event.",
                this.activity, this, this);
        return;
    }
    activityRequestPermission();
}

private static void showMessageOKCancel(String message, Activity activity,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener okListener,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener cancelListener) {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(activity).setMessage(message)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", okListener).create().show();
}

@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.activity, new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
                LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    } else if (which == DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Application was denied permission!");

    }

}

private void activityRequestPermission() {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.activity, new String[] {
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION },
            LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
}

public void onRequestPermissionResult(int requestCode,
        String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            enablePlaceMonitoring();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Application was denied permission!");
        }

    }
}

private void enablePlaceMonitoring() {

    final SimpleDateFormat dateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat(
            "MM/dd/yyyy, hh:mm:ss", Locale.UK);
    final String dateTimeStr;

    beaconEventListener = new BeaconEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBeaconSighting(BeaconSighting beaconSighting) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBeaconSighting(beaconSighting);
            String UUID = beaconSighting.getBeacon().getUuid();
            String beaconName = beaconSighting.getBeacon().getName();
            String identifier = beaconSighting.getBeacon().getIdentifier();
            Integer RSSI = beaconSighting.getRSSI();
            long dateTime = beaconSighting.getTimeInMillis();
            String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss")
                    .format(new Date(dateTime));

            listAdapter.add(beaconName.toString() + " " + dateString+"Rssi: "+RSSI);
            Log.i("GBeaconListener", "Name: " + beaconName + " RSSI: "
                    + RSSI + " DateTime: " + dateString);
        }

    };

    placeEventListener = new PlaceEventListener() {
        String dateTimeStr;

        @Override
        public void onVisitStart(Visit visit) {

            dateTimeStr = dateFormate
                    .format(visit.getArrivalTimeInMillis());
            listAdapter.add(String.format("Start Visit for %s,\n %s", visit
                    .getPlace().getName(), dateTimeStr.toString()));
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onVisitEnd(Visit visit) {
            dateTimeStr = dateFormate.format(visit
                    .getDepartureTimeInMillis());
            listAdapter.add(String.format("End Visit for %s,\n %s", visit
                    .getPlace().getName(), dateTimeStr.toString()));
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBeaconSighting(BeaconSighting beaconSighting,
                List<Visit> list) {
            super.onBeaconSighting(beaconSighting, list);

            String UUID = beaconSighting.getBeacon().getUuid();
            String beaconName = beaconSighting.getBeacon().getName();
            String identifier = beaconSighting.getBeacon().getIdentifier();
            Integer RSSI = beaconSighting.getRSSI();
            long dateTime = beaconSighting.getTimeInMillis();
            String dateString = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss",Locale.UK)
                    .format(new Date(dateTime));
            // listAdapter.add(
            // beaconName.toString() +" " + dateString );

            Log.i("GPlaceListener", "Name: " + beaconName + " RSSI: "
                    + RSSI + " DateTime: " + dateString);

        }
    };

    beaconManager = new BeaconManager();
    beaconManager.addListener(beaconEventListener);

    placeManager = PlaceManager.getInstance();
    placeManager.addListener(placeEventListener);

    placeManager.startMonitoring();
    beaconManager.startListening();

    CommunicationManager.getInstance().startReceivingCommunications();
}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="19"
            android:targetSdkVersion="23" />


        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
            <activity
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="8487000"/>
        </application>

    </manifest>
```

Logs:

```
    04-03 14:48:27.378: V/ActivityThread(30746): Handling launch of ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}} startsNotResumed=false
04-03 14:48:27.378: V/ActivityThread(30746): ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}}: app=android.app.Application@ef9b66b, appName=com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android, pkg=com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android, comp={com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}, dir=/data/app/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android-1/base.apk
04-03 14:48:27.415: V/ActivityThread(30746): Performing resume of ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}}
04-03 14:48:27.416: D/ActivityThread(30746): ACT-AM_ON_RESUME_CALLED ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}}
04-03 14:48:27.416: V/ActivityThread(30746): Resume ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}} started activity: false, hideForNow: false, finished: false
04-03 14:48:27.416: V/PhoneWindow(30746): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 4 ,Parent =null, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4b5cd50 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-03 14:48:27.417: D/WindowClient(30746): Add to mViews: com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4b5cd50 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}, this = android.view.WindowManagerGlobal@6d3b7fb
04-03 14:48:27.418: D/OpenGLRenderer(30746): CanvasContext() 0x7fa98e5800
04-03 14:48:27.420: D/ViewRootImpl(30746): hardware acceleration is enabled, this = ViewRoot{914d962 com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity,ident = 2}
04-03 14:48:27.427: V/ActivityThread(30746): Resuming ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}} with isForward=true
04-03 14:48:27.427: V/PhoneWindow(30746): DecorView setVisiblity: visibility = 0 ,Parent =ViewRoot{914d962 com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity,ident = 2}, this =com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{4b5cd50 V.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
04-03 14:48:27.428: V/ActivityThread(30746): Scheduling idle handler for ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}}
04-03 14:48:27.432: D/ActivityThread(30746): ACT-LAUNCH_ACTIVITY handled : 0 / ActivityRecord{88c3202 token=android.os.BinderProxy@a7a1713 {com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity}}
04-03 14:48:27.450: D/Surface(30746): Surface::allocateBuffers(this=0x7f94fbb400)
04-03 14:48:27.450: D/OpenGLRenderer(30746): CanvasContext() 0x7fa98e5800 initialize window=0x7f94fbb410, title=com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android/com.gimbal.hello_gimbal_android.MainActivity
04-03 14:48:27.450: D/Surface(30746): Surface::connect(this=0x7f94fbb400,api=1)
04-03 14:48:27.452: W/libEGL(30746): [ANDROID_RECORDABLE] format: 1
04-03 14:48:27.455: D/mali_winsys(30746): new_window_surface returns 0x3000
04-03 14:48:27.464: V/InputMethodManager(30746): onWindowFocus: android.widget.ListView{7c335d6 VFED.VC.. .F....ID 32,32-688,1008 #7f080000 app:id/list} softInputMode=272 first=true flags=#1810100
04-03 14:48:27.464: V/InputMethodManager(30746): START INPUT: android.widget.ListView{7c335d6 VFED.VC.. .F....ID 32,32-688,1008 #7f080000 app:id/list} ic=null tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@37edadc controlFlags=#105
04-03 14:48:27.480: I/[MALI][Gralloc](30746): [+]r_hnd(0x7fab9a7ce0), client(28), share_fd(40)
04-03 14:48:27.480: D/GraphicBuffer(30746): register, handle(0x7fab9a7ce0) (w:720 h:1184 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-03 14:48:28.652: I/[MALI][Gralloc](30746): [+]r_hnd(0x7fab9a7380), client(28), share_fd(41)
04-03 14:48:28.652: D/GraphicBuffer(30746): register, handle(0x7fab9a7380) (w:720 h:1184 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-03 14:48:28.669: I/[MALI][Gralloc](30746): [+]r_hnd(0x7fab9a79c0), client(28), share_fd(43)
04-03 14:48:28.670: D/GraphicBuffer(30746): register, handle(0x7fab9a79c0) (w:720 h:1184 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-03 14:48:28.686: I/[MALI][Gralloc](30746): [+]r_hnd(0x7fab9a7ba0), client(28), share_fd(44)
04-03 14:48:28.686: D/GraphicBuffer(30746): register, handle(0x7fab9a7ba0) (w:720 h:1184 s:720 f:0x1 u:0x000b00)
04-03 14:49:01.283: V/InputMethodManager(30746): onWindowFocus: android.widget.ListView{7c335d6 VFED.VC.. .F.....D 32,32-688,1008 #7f080000 app:id/list} softInputMode=16 first=false flags=#181
```

More Logs:

```
04-04 00:37:45.138: D/NativeCrypto(3035): ssl=0x7f94e67480 NativeCrypto_SSL_interrupt
04-04 00:37:45.138: D/NativeCrypto(3035):  sslNotify, appData=0x7f94ccb500 ret=1
04-04 00:37:45.138: D/NativeCrypto(3035):  sslNotify, appData=0x7f94ccb500 ret=1
04-04 00:37:45.138: D/NativeCrypto(3035): ssl=0x7f94e67480 info_callback where=0x4008 ret=256
04-04 00:37:45.138: D/NativeCrypto(3035): ssl=0x7f94e67480 SSL3 alert write:W:CN warning close notify
04-04 00:37:45.139: D/NativeCrypto(3035): ssl=0x7f94e67480 info_callback ignored
04-04 00:37:45.139: I/System.out(3035): close [socket][/10.66.51.2:49434]
`
```

**output of Try2:**

**Not Working InFocus M460:**

[image: Try2 Not Working]

**Working  other devices: Shows Beacons / Geofence / place logs.**

[image: Try2 Working]

**Updates:**

Infocus Bingo50 is Encrypted by default. Again Gimbal Sample app is not able to sight / scan beacon.  I tested in 3rd party beacon scanning app (scan iBeacon) from this device, beacon logs received but not in sample app.

[image]

Updated Logs:

```
05-31 18:49:01.876 17875-17875/com.gimbal.android.sample I/-----: Using android logger factory
05-31 18:49:02.031 17875-17875/com.gimbal.android.sample E/WifiManager: mWifiServiceMessenger == null
05-31 18:49:02.414 17875-18190/com.gimbal.android.sample E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)
05-31 18:49:07.481 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=registration.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:07.481 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:07.482 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=registration.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:07.482 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:08.493 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: registration.gimbal.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
05-31 18:49:08.874 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=registration.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:08.874 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:09.255 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa84e1580 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f921f4370 arg=0x0
05-31 18:49:09.255 17875-18269/com.gimbal.android.sample E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa84e1580 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
05-31 18:49:10.381 17875-18213/com.gimbal.android.sample W/G.d: [PropertyChangeNotif] Failed to update places: Unable to refresh place bubble, no fix available
05-31 18:49:10.416 17875-17935/com.gimbal.android.sample D/BluetoothLeScanner: onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=5
05-31 18:49:10.424 17875-18213/com.gimbal.android.sample I/BluetoothLeScanner: startRegisteration: mLeScanClients={com.gimbal.proximity.core.bluetooth.k$1@2838227=android.bluetooth.le.BluetoothLeScanner$BleScanCallbackWrapper@4d07cd4}
05-31 18:49:11.234 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=placebubble.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:11.237 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:11.246 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=placebubble.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:11.246 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:11.323 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: placebubble.gimbal.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
05-31 18:49:11.625 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=placebubble.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:11.625 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:11.966 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa84e2200 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f9223e3b0 arg=0x0
05-31 18:49:11.967 17875-18278/com.gimbal.android.sample E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7fa84e2200 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
05-31 18:49:12.564 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=android.api.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:12.564 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:12.564 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=android.api.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:12.564 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=1024; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:12.607 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: getaddrinfo: android.api.gimbal.com get result from proxy gai_error = 0
05-31 18:49:12.912 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: hostname=android.api.gimbal.com; servname=(null); netid=0; mark=0
05-31 18:49:12.912 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample D/libc-netbsd: [getaddrinfo]: ai_addrlen=0; ai_canonname=(null); ai_flags=4; ai_family=0
05-31 18:49:13.243 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f91ea8700 cert_verify_callback x509_store_ctx=0x7f91939370 arg=0x0
05-31 18:49:13.243 17875-18283/com.gimbal.android.sample E/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x7f91ea8700 cert_verify_callback calling verifyCertificateChain authMethod=ECDHE_RSA
```

Comment: On the M460, do you actually see the location permission prompt?  Do you know that it is granted?

Comment: @davidgyoung yes sir it is granted, when first time app is execute.

Comment: Does the M460 have internet access?  This may be needed to resolve the Gimbal identifier using the Gimbal SDK.

Comment: @davidgyoung M460 have 3G internet connection.

Comment: @vishal I also want to integrate this sdk.which is best place to integrate?at application level it is possible?because as you see this code is in Main Activity so when MainActivity will be finished detection will be stopped? I want to track this through out the app.

Comment: @jay For detect beacon / geofence i used native service. once app is started then service is called. so if application is in background or not in Activity statck even detection is running in background. Above code is just for simply detect beacon.

Comment: @vishal I only want to detect when app is open

Comment: @vishal how you checked for marshmallow permission for location access within your service?

Comment: @jay if you wish to beacon is detect when app is open. no need to use background service. just call listener only (like PlaceEventListner or BeaconEventListener of gimbal beacon ). For permission see SDK 2.40 demo code